# Is there a way to put compressed file in the same folder from which it compressed the text files?

Tags: .net, powershell

I've a folder `C:\FolderOne\TextFile.txt`.

```
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory(C:\FolderOne, C:\FolderOne)
```

Expected:

```
C:\FolderOne\TextFile.zip, TextFile.txt
```

It is giving the error that it cannot access TextFile.zip as it has been used by other process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as far as I'm aware. You get this error because the zip file is created first, and then populated with the required files.

You could work around this:

```
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory(C:\FolderOne, C:\Temp)

Move-Item C:\Temp\TextFile.zip C:\FolderOne
```